# Getting a timeout error from a stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure to retrieve data from a database (dynamic query). I am calling this stored procedure from C# code, passing two parameters to this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCompleteCPTDetails]
    @Practice_Short_Name varchar(50),
    @Uploaded_Date nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CPTtablename nvarchar(300)
    DECLARE @vQuery NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @upldate nvarchar(100)

    SET @upldate = @Uploaded_Date
    SET @CPTtablename = 'ACER_CLAIMS_MASTER_DETAIL_Hist_' + @Practice_Short_Name
    SET @vQuery = 'SELECT Practice_Short_Name, Service_Date_From, Carrier_Name,
   Location_Description, Patient_Number, Patient_First_Name,
   Patient_Last_Name, Voucher_Number, Procedure_Code, Service_Fees,
   Service_Payments, Service_Adjustments, Acer_Status, Acer_Allowed_Amount
   FROM ' +@CPTtablename+' 
   WHERE Uploaded_Date =''' + @upldate + ''' 
   ORDER BY acer_status ASC, Service_Date_From DESC, Patient_First_Name ASC'

    EXEC (@vQuery)
END
```

But when I am running this query I get a timeout error. If I assign value to my parameters in the stored procedure and run it from query windows then it is showing correct data.

Can anyone please explain to me why I get a timeout error if I am calling it from C#?

Comment: Well for starters, how long does it take to execute? The default timeout for  `SqlCommand` is 30 seconds and I presume you are using this in `C#`; therefore if this procedure takes more than 30 seconds to execute, you will get a CommandTimeout Exception.

Comment: Stop writing bad SQL code, others might copy it. Your SP is under-performing and vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Try calling a much simple procedure (e.g. SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SomeTable) - do you still get a timeout? Often a "timeout issue" is really due to a bad connection string.

Comment: Could you tell us how many rows are in the table? Is the column uploaded_date indexed?

Comment: Also, if there are other processes that are updating the same set of rows then your query may be waiting for that process to complete before retrieving the result. In this case, you can use the NOLOCK table hints if you can live with potential out of date data.

Comment: i tried everything remove order by, removed where condition only one column i passed, even select top 1 row. but still it is throwing Timeout Error.

Answer (score 1):

That is a pretty simple where and order by.
Unless that is just a massive table with no indexes that should be fast.
Is there an index on Uploaded_Date and is it not fragmented.
Also an index on the sort would help.

Are you loading everything into a DataTable?
If so try loading into DataReader.

Try a top 1 and remove the order by.
If that does not return then you have connection issue as no way that query should time out.

The other thing to try is with (no lock) to see if it is a lock problem.

Why is @Uploaded_Date nvarchar(max)?
Is that a date or not?

Comment: I tried your solution but still it is throwing TimeOut Error.

Answer (score -1):

There can be many solutions to this  problem, as problem areas can be different in each case.

But most common:

1. Check & increase sqlcommand timeout in your application
2. Try calling this SP asynchronously

Also i would like to know, your application on the same machine where DB resides?

Comment: Large count would not cause a timeout.  If it return the first record before the timeout then the clock stops.

Comment: What if SP performing complex operations and talking time to return even single record ?

Comment: But that is not your answer.  You said it was timing due to number of records returned.

Comment: Can you justify that it would not show timeout error if i have less timeout specified in connection string and i have huge data to return ?

Comment: I agree, i confused with SQL connection timeout and Query excecution timeout.

Comment: What evidence do you have this is huge data?  OP states is runs fine from query window.   Based on the names it is just patient data.

Comment: I considered a scenario where data is huge and answered accordingly.

Comment: But you did not just consider a scenario you stated that is the problem.  If the data is huge then why would management studio work?  SSMS is just client with timeout also.

Comment: SQL Server compiles queries and maintains its plan cache.
Perhaps you should go through some articles which explains why SSMS is fast but not application.
Learn how SQL Server compiles a stored procedure, what parameter sniffing is and why it is part of the equation in the vast majority of these confusing situations.
Without knowing much details this was the quick fix i could think of, which many times worked for me.
I also said "there can be many solutions to this", which hints my answer is open for reconsideration.

Comment: SSMS is just a client.  You state "This is because your query has huge records to return" and you don't know that.  Based on column names and the fact it runs in SSMS the is highly unlikely.  Change that to "a cause could be".  Come on it runs in SSMS but not the application because of cached query plan.